# Adding SQL Server 2008 R2 (sqlexpress) datasource in CF Administrator

Tags: sql-server-2008, coldfusion, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using coldfusion 9 and SQL Server 2008 R2. It is set up as sqlexpress When I try to add a data source (sql) I get this error:

```
Connection verification failed for data source: test_cursor
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver]The requested instance is either invalid or not running.
The root cause was that: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver]The requested instance is either invalid or not running.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you are accessing SQL Server Express remotely, ensure that the TCP/IP protocol has been enabled by using the "SQL Server Configuration Manager", which is in the "Configuration Tools" folder.